# Can't reset eclipse syntax coloring back after importing preference settings

Tags: eclipse, syntax, settings, syntax-highlighting, user-preferences

So I imported an .epf file to import a user's settings for syntax color and highlighting. But now when I try to go back to the defaults, it doesn't change. I'm thinking it has overwritten the defaults. Maybe if I re-install eclipse or if I can get a back up of default settings from someone else and import those instead.

Is there anyway to get the defaults back without doing the above?